# Time arithmetic with moment

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

In This Meteor server side code for the users collections, the property `createdAt` shows something like this `ISODate("2017-02-09T01:22:30.894Z")`.
And in another collection `myCol` I have the `createdAt` property with the unix timestamp in milliseconds.
Moment.js is installed.
How can I check the following condition:
myCol.createdAt is after n months from the end of the month when the user was created. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that should work (there are of course a handful of other ways to do this...this was the first one that came to mind).

You can convert the Users `createdAt` property to a moment object like this (assuming your user doc is stored in a var called `userOne`).

`var moment1 = moment(userOne.createdAt);`

Then, you can convert the unix timestamp in the other collection like this (assuming the doc is stored in a var called `doc`).

`var moment2 = moment(doc.createdAt);`

Now find the end of the moment for moment1 and add in 'N' months.

`moment1.endOf('month').add(N, 'months');`

Finally, do your comparison.

`moment2.isAfter(moment1);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get that string representation of the `ISODate` object, perhaps just `.toString()`.

However, this is how you can get the time difference in months with the `myCol.createdAt` represented by the current date `Date.now()`.

```js
var isoString = "2017-02-09T01:22:30.894Z"
var today = Date.now()
console.log(moment(isoString).diff(today, 'months'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```